# List of all months and year between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to explain the details so that this is easy to understand.

I want a list of month and year based on the difference of month and year.

I am implementing search functionality based on start month with year and end month with year.
So!

**start Selection - 01(month)-2009 (Yr)**

**End selection 10(month)-2009 (Yr)**

What I want from MySQL is:

```
Month                        Year
JAN                          2009
FEB                          2009
MAR                          2009
APR                          2009
MAY                          2009
JUN                          2009
JUL                          2009
AUG                          2009
SEP                          2009
OCT                          2009
```

Comment: Looks like a homework problem to me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FractalizeR answer is the right one.

Just let me expand by defining the functions:

```
function GetMonthsFromDate($myDate) {
  $year = (int) date('Y',$myDate);
  $months = (int) date('m', $myDate);
  $dateAsMonths = 12*$year + $months;
  return $dateAsMonths;
}

function GetDateFromMonths($months) {
  $years = (int) $months / 12;
  $month = (int) $months % 12;
  $myDate = strtotime("$years/$month/01"); //makes a date like 2009/12/01
  return $myDate;
}
```

PS: tried to post as a comment but the formating got screwed.
(Of course this functions could be rewritten as one liners but wanted to be more readable)

Comment: Great functions, although in GetDateFromMonths, using (int) $months / 12 returns a float and is thus unusable in the strtotime function. I got this working by just replacing `$years = (int) ($months / 12);
$month = (int) ($months % 12);`

Comment: thank you for the functions, but I did encounter some issues to which I have put (my) solutions in another answer

Answer (score 8):

You need to write some functions to  convert your dates to a number of months passed since certain date and back. For example, since Jan 1980.

```
Jan 1980 = 0;
Dec 1980 = 12;
Jan 1981 = 13 etc.
```

Then you just do simple "for" loop:

```
for ($i = GetMonthsFromDate($StartDate), $i <= GetMonthsFromDate($StopDate), $i++) {
   echo(GetDateFromMonths($i));
}
```

Comment: This is the right anser for this question.
Just let me expand by defining the functions:

   function GetMonthsFromDate ($myDate) {
      $year = (int) date('Y',$myDate);
      $months = (int) date('m', $myDate);
      $dateAsMonths = 12*$year +months;
      return $dateMonths;
   }

   function GetDateFromMonths ($months) {
      $years = (int) $months / 12;
      $month = (int) $months % 12;
      $myDate = strtotime("$years/$month/1);
      return $myDate;
   }
   

(Of course this functions could be rewritten as one liners but wanted to be more readable)

Answer (score 8):

Although FractalizeR answer is the correct one.
There is another option.

Taking advantage from the fact that that strtotime('2009/08/01 - 1 month') will do the right thing and delete 1 month.

```
<?php
$startDate = strtotime("$startYear/$startMonth/01");
$endDate   = strtotime("$endYear/$endMonth/01");

$currentDate = $endDate;

while ($currentDate >= $startDate) {
    echo date('Y/m',$currentDate);
    $currentDate = strtotime( date('Y/m/01/',$currentDate).' -1 month');
}
```

Again a list of months

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, I think, good stuff to get things done quickly.

Comment: Actually, I prefer this one over the solution by FractalizeR and this should be the correct answer. More straightforward code and easy to adapt to other purposes (simply jump 2 months, trimesters, years, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final answer which is worked very great

```
$startMonth= $_POST['startmonth'];
    $startyear= $_POST['startyear'];
    $cYear = $startyear;

    $endMonth= $_POST['endmonth'];
    $endyear= $_POST['endyear'];
    $sql = "SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(".$endyear.$endMonth.", ".$startyear.$startMonth.")";
    $queryRS =  $db->query($sql);
    $tmonthsarray = $db->fetchRow($c_jobsVat);
    $totalmonths=tmonthsarray[0];
         for($count=$startMonth; $count <= ($startMonth + $totalmonths);$count++)
         {  
            $processYear = $startyear + intval( ( $count - 1 ) / 12 );
        $processMonth= (( $count - 1 ) % 12 + 1);
        $processMonthName= date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$count));
         }
```

Comment: That's a bad, but may be working, solution. It involves issuing SQL query and this is time consuming. Better to do all from PHP

Answer (score 1):

I wrote that function based on you guys's input. Check this out:

```
function CountTheMonth($startDate,$endDate,$order)
{
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
    $endDate   = strtotime($endDate);

    $ASC_Month = $startDate;
    $DESC_Month = $endDate;
    $Y_Axis = Array();

    if($order == 'DESC')//Big to small
    {
        while ($DESC_Month >= $startDate) 
        {    
            $Y_Axis[] = date('F-Y',$DESC_Month);
            $DESC_Month = strtotime( date('Y-m-d',$DESC_Month).' -1 month');
        }
        return $Y_Axis;
    }
    elseif($order == 'ASC')//Small to big
    {
        while ($ASC_Month <= $endDate) 
        {    
            $Y_Axis[] = date('F-Y',$ASC_Month);
            $ASC_Month = strtotime( date('Y-m-d',$ASC_Month).' +1 month');
        }
        return $Y_Axis;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic works great to get a list of months. But not sure how we can deal with years in this case.

Here is my code:

```
$startMonth= $_POST['startmonth'];

$startyear= $_POST['startyear'];

$endMonth= $_POST['endmonth'];

$endyear= $_POST['endyear'];

$sql = "SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(".$endyear.$endMonth.", ".$startyear.$startMonth.")";

$queryRS =  $db->query($sql);

$tmonthsarray = $db->fetchRow($c_jobsVat);

$totalmonths= $tmonthsarray[0]; 

for($count=$startMonth; $count <= ($startMonth + $totalmonths);$count++)
{
    echo "<BR>==>".date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$count)) ; // Months

    // what comes here in case of listing year
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the solution of @FractalizeR and the addition by @elviejo , it helped me forward. But I believe I encountered some issues, and they might of help to others: (+ please correct me if I am wrong)

1. **Important to note:** both `$StartDate` and `$StopDate` are of type `timestamp`, not actually the `date`-type <sup>(1)</sup>. So I changed the function parameters to `$myTimestamp` in the hope of not confuse others.

For example:

```
$StartDate = strtotime("Sept 2010");
$StopDate = time(); // current timestamp
```

2. For the functions of @elviejo:

   1. typecasting: a simple `(int)` didn't work for me (PHP5), so I used `intval()` instead
   2. working with `%` gives results ranging from 0 to 11, while months are in the range of 1 to 12 <sup>(2)</sup>. So in the function `GetDateFromMonths($months)`, we have to `+1` the result
   3. Because we add 1 to the `%`  in the function `GetDateFromMonths($months)`, we will have to substract 1 from the `$dateAsMonths` in the function `GetMonthsFromDate($myTimestamp)`.

This gives me the following code:

```
function GetMonthsFromDate($myTimestamp)
{
  $year = (int) date('Y',$myTimestamp);
  $months = (int) date('m', $myTimestamp);
  $dateAsMonths = 12*$year + $months - 1;
  return $dateAsMonths;
}

function GetDateFromMonths($months)
{
  $years = intval($months / 12);
  $month = intval($months % 12) + 1;
  $myTimestamp = strtotime("$years/$month/01"); //makes a date like 2009/12/01, and translate it to a timestamp
  return $myTimestamp;
}
```

Started by the following `for`-loop:

```
for ($i = GetMonthsFromDate($StartDate); $i <= GetMonthsFromDate($StopDate); $i++)
{
    echo(date('d M Y',GetDateFromMonths($i))."</br>");
}
```

Which gave the wanted result. Do my remarks make sense?

---

Notes:

<sup>(1)</sup> I don't even think `date` exists as a [type in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php), but I might be wrong.

<sup>(2)</sup> January is 1, February is 2, ... November is 11 but December is **0**. This will not give the wanted result.